# JS str.replace(regex, function) is not being greedy

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this regex, which grabs a newline-separated block of text where all lines are indented by two spaces:

```
chorusRegex = /((?:(?:\n|^)  .*)+)/g
```

On regex101 (see exact snippet here https://regex101.com/r/BFMtHP/1) it works fine (grabs the whole block as one match), but when I do this:

```
lyrics = lyrics.replace(chorusRegex, function($0, $1) {
  return "<div class='chorus'>" + $1 + "</div>"
})
```

Instead of putting the div around each indented block of text, it puts divs around each line that's indented.

Why is `lyrics.replace` not being greedy, and instead repeating over each line?

## Edit

I have this as `lyrics`

```
"[D]No tenemos Sumo [A]Sacerdote que
No [Bm]se compadece en [G]mi debilidad
[D]Sino Uno que fue [A]tentado en todo [Bm]igual
Que nosotros[G]
[]Sin pecado. 

  [D]Vamos confiada[A]mente 
  Al [Bm]trono de la [G]gracia por
  [D]Misericordia, [A]gracia
  Y opor[Bm]tuno so[G]corro h[D]allar. 

  sadf
  sadf
  weqrqwer"
```

And I want the `replace` function to produce this:

```
"[D]No tenemos Sumo [A]Sacerdote que
No [Bm]se compadece en [G]mi debilidad
[D]Sino Uno que fue [A]tentado en todo [Bm]igual
Que nosotros[G]
[]Sin pecado. 

<div class='chorus'> 
  [D]Vamos confiada[A]mente 
  Al [Bm]trono de la [G]gracia por
  [D]Misericordia, [A]gracia
  Y opor[Bm]tuno so[G]corro h[D]allar. 
</div>

<div class='chorus'> 
  sadf
  sadf
  weqrqwer 
</div>"
```

But the problem is my current code is producing this:

```
"[D]No tenemos Sumo [A]Sacerdote que
No [Bm]se compadece en [G]mi debilidad
[D]Sino Uno que fue [A]tentado en todo [Bm]igual
Que nosotros[G]
[]Sin pecado. 

<div class='chorus'> 
  [D]Vamos confiada[A]mente   
</div>
<div class='chorus'> 
  Al [Bm]trono de la [G]gracia por 
</div>
<div class='chorus'> 
  [D]Misericordia, [A]gracia 
</div>
<div class='chorus'> 
  Y opor[Bm]tuno so[G]corro h[D]allar. 
</div>"
```

Comment: what is your expected output? lyrics is the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var lyrics = "[D]No tenemos Sumo [A]Sacerdote que\n\
No [Bm]se compadece en [G]mi debilidad\n\
[D]Sino Uno que fue [A]tentado en todo [Bm]igual\n\
Que nosotros[G]\n\
[]Sin pecado.\n\
\n\
  [D]Vamos confiada[A]mente\n\
  Al [Bm]trono de la [G]gracia por\n\
  [D]Misericordia, [A]gracia\n\
  Y opor[Bm]tuno so[G]corro h[D]allar.\n\
\n\
  sadf\n\
  sadf\n\
  weqrqwer",

  chorusRegex = /((?:(?:\n|^)  .*)+)/g;

lyrics = lyrics.replace(chorusRegex, "<div class='chorus'>$1</div>");

console.log(lyrics)
```

Comment: Yes I found this to work, but only when `lyrics` is a template literal (no idea why). Can you figure out how to work it out when `lyrics` is simply a double-quoted string?

Comment: Oh I found out there were `\r\n` characters instead of simply `\n` (from windows users). Cheers!